# Run script on iterator returned by `glob` with Rust's `run_cmd`

Tags: python, rust, path, iterator, glob

Just a quick disclaimer to let you know that I'm a complete Rust illiterate. Taking that out of the way I can move to the question.

I'm trying to run a Python script on an iterator returned by `glob` with Rust's `run_cmd`. In other words, I'm trying to run a Python script which takes a file name and an integer as command line inputs and I wish to run this script only on files with a specific extension.

To grab the files with the extension I desire I'm using Rust's `glob` crate to return an iterator with the paths of these files. Having this iterator, I'm trying to run the following code to pass them to the Python script:

```rust
use cmd_lib::*;
use rayon::prelude::*;
use glob::glob;

fn main() {
    glob("../split_parsed/*.output")
        .into_par_iter()
        .for_each(|pattern|{
            run_cmd!(./src/aggregate.py ${pattern} 500).unwrap();
        });
}
```

Running this I get the following error:

```
error[E0599]: the method `to_string` exists for struct `Paths`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:9:13
   |
9  |             run_cmd!(./src/aggregate.py ${pattern} 500).unwrap();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Paths` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   | 
  ::: /home/ducbueno/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/glob-0.3.0/src/lib.rs:88:1
   |
88 | pub struct Paths {
   | ----------------
   | |
   | doesn't satisfy `Paths: ToString`
   | doesn't satisfy `Paths: std::fmt::Display`
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `Paths: std::fmt::Display`
           which is required by `Paths: ToString`
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `aggregate`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name aggregate --edition=2018 src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=d0ac83c95bbb3012 -C extra-filename=-d0ac83c95bbb3012 --out-dir /hdd/mysrc/parse_gem5_debug/aggregate/target/debug/deps -C incremental=/hdd/mysrc/parse_gem5_debug/aggregate/target/debug/incremental -L dependency=/hdd/mysrc/parse_gem5_debug/aggregate/target/debug/deps --extern cmd_lib=/hdd/mysrc/parse_gem5_debug/aggregate/target/debug/deps/libcmd_lib-db4ce11b465defbd.rlib --extern glob=/hdd/mysrc/parse_gem5_debug/aggregate/target/debug/deps/libglob-99b91896bb92b644.rlib --extern rayon=/hdd/mysrc/parse_gem5_debug/aggregate/target/debug/deps/librayon-a4ecce8f6a92d238.rlib` (exit code: 1)
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Also any suggestions would be extremely welcome.

Thanks!

PS - Another quick disclaimer: I want to use Rust to execute this task due to the possibility of running the Python scripts in the files in parallel with Rayon. I had a great experience in the past using the parallel capabilities offered by Rayon in the past and would like to use it again.

Edit - full error message.

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading through the [Error Handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) chapter of the Rust Book, particularly the section that goes over `Result`.

The function call `glob("../split_parsed/*.output")` can fail (presumably due to I/O reasons) and therefore returns a [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html). You're being fooled by `.into_par_iter()` here because `Result` *is* also an iterator (it yields a single element if successful, none otherwise). So what you get in your `.for_each()` is the full `Paths` object, which isn't what you want.

Here's a working sample:

```rust
fn main() {
    glob("../split_parsed/*.output")
        .expect("globbing failed")
        .map(|path| path.expect("globbing failed"))
        .par_bridge()
        .for_each(|path| {
            run_cmd!(./src/aggregate.py ${path} 500).unwrap();
        });
}
```

I use `.expect()` here to crash the program if the initial globbing or if the subsequent querying fails. Then use `.par_bridge()` instead of `.into_par_iter()` since `Paths` doesn't implement it. Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: You can use the `par_bridge` method to iterate directly over the the iterator and avoid the extra `collect`.

Comment: @Aiden4 ah thanks! I knew it was somewhere. I've updated the answer.